# How can I launch a GUI app on boot in Crostini?

Tags: linux, x11, chromebook, crostini

I would like to launch a GUI app (Firefox, for example) every time my Linux OS boots in my Chromebook. The Linux OS boots whenever the first Linux app is launched. I've tried a number of techniques, but can't make any of them work.

**1. .desktop in `~/.config/autostart` or in `/etc/xdg/autostart`**

This fails to launch Firefox on boot even though the firefox.desktop file itself launches Firefox with no problem. Would I need permissions set in some special way, or something else, for this to work right?

**2. Launch it via `.bashrc`**

This launches Firefox when the terminal is launched, not necessarily when Crostini boots. If I boot Crostini by opening a different Linux app than the terminal (like Chromium for example), then `.bashrc` doesn't get called.

**3. Launch it via `/etc/profile.d`**

Same problem as `.bashrc`. It only launches Firefox when the terminal starts up, not when Crostini boots per-se.

**4. systemd unit file launching a bash script that launches Firefox**

This (so far) fails to launch Firefox on startup even though it can launch Firefox with no problem when I run the service manually. Here is the code for my service file, which is placed in `/etc/systemd/system/` with `chmod 640` perms:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firefox launcher

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment="Displat=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/mypath/fflauncher.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

And here is the code for `fflauncher.sh`, which has `chmod +x` perms:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
while [ 1 ]
do
  if [ -S /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 ]
  then
    xhost local:
    firefox &
    exit 0
  fi
  ((++COUNTER))
  if [ $COUNTER -gt 20 ]
  then
    exit 1
  fi
  sleep 0.5
done
```

Nevertheless, Firefox does not launch on startup. But interestingly, the bash script itself ***is*** actually called on startup using this method. The Firefox app just doesn't run.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get this to work?